# Why does my UPS break AC adaptors?

Tags: ups

I've got a couple of my AC adaptors fail at different times during what I assume were power spikes, while being connected to my UPS. It's a pretty old APC 500 which I use only to back up my router and external hard drive. Though it's couple of years old and I havent changed the battery ever it still gives me around 5 minutes of power so I can shut down everything properly.

First when my router's AC failed I thought it was just faulty, then later when hard drive's AC failed also, I started to think that the problem is the UPS as other AC that were connected directly to the grid stayed fine.

So the question is: should I replace my UPS with a newer one, or is the whole idea of connecting appliances AC adapters to UPS just wrong and it's only for PC ACs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you replaced the power adapters and found that the devices still work? Have you bench tested the failed power adapters or tried them on other devices (assuming you have another device with the same plug and power requirements)?

If you mean that both the power adapters (i.e. [“wall wart” or inline brick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_wart)) for your router and external HD have gone bad while attached to your UPS, then maybe your UPS is the problem. I would find it abhorrent that a UPS would fail a way that would destroy a connected device's power conversion hardware, but I suppose it is possible.

It should be fine to power non-PC devices through a UPS. You would not want to run high-draw devices through a UPS (think [Blendtec](http://www.blendtec.com/) or [KitchenAid](http://www.kitchenaid.com/)), but a router and external HD should be fine (both should draw less power than a whole PC).

Comment: Yes after replacing power adapters both router and HD work fine, though I havent tried the failed ones on other devices. I think I'll replace the UPS then. Just wanted to know that I'm not doing something stupid. Thanks

Comment: Printers are one common high-current draw IT device, that often should _not_ be connected to a UPS, unless the UPS is properly rated for it.

Answer (score 0):

Many inline AC-to-DC power adapters are poorly design and use subpar components.
I wouldn't expect one that's included by the manufacturer in the package with a reputable name-brand device to be a problem, but a lot of the replacement ones are terrible.  And there are some blatant counterfeits out there made to look like a name-brand but are of inferior quality.

That said, having more than one fail at the same time does suggest an external problem.

The surge suppression built into quality power strips does not last forever.  They use metal oxide varistors (MOVs) to absorb sudden spikes.  They can protect your devices from one huge spike, a couple big spikes, or years' worth of smaller spikes.  But each event does a little damage to the MOVs, reducing its ability to react to future spikes.  (Just as the bumpers on modern cars are worthless after one collision and should be replaced.)

The surge suppression built into the battery-backed sockets on a UPS are generally more resilient than that of a power strip.  But the extra outlets on the UPS typically have just the same kind of suppression as a good power strip.  Either way, if your UPS has seen a lot of action, and you want good spike protection for your devices, it might be time to replace it.